# PeriodogramArray or PowerSpectralDensity?

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing

could anyone explain what is the difference between PowerSpectralDensity[data,omega] and PeriodogramArray[data]? When I plot them (starting from the same set of data of course) I get two different curves, and I cannot figure out what is their relationship. I expect them to be somehow related. 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!